# Vertically spelled words in a table

Tags: tables, rotating

I have made the following table in LaTeX. In order to vertically rotate the headers (extraction/production, transportation,...) in the table I have used the `\rotatebox` command. However, I would like to vertically spell these headers so that they are readable in a presentation without turning my slide.

[image: Table life cycle phases]

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! By 'vertically spelling', you mean to have the letters the right way up, and stacked on top of each other? Personally, I don't think that makes it more readable.

Comment: Yes, I would like to write each letter of a header under the previous letter of that word, so stacking them by starting from the top and vertically going down in the column. An alternative might be to rotate the text over 45 degrees (for example), but then the table would be too wide to fit on my slide...

Answer (score 4):

There are, of course, other issues that need addressing, with `multicol` or such, but here I merely demonstrate how to set words "vertically".  I set them in various styles, in hopes you could find something that suited your legibility requirement.

The stacks work this way because (for historical reasons), the stack end-of-line (EOL) in `stackengine` is a blank space, unless the package is invoked with the `[usestackEOL]` option, which makes the stack EOL a `\\`.  In any event, the stack EOL can be changed with the `\setstackEOL{}` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\parskip 1em
\begin{document}
\setstackgap{L}{9pt}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
Material & Construction & Use\\
\hline
\Longstack{\strut E x t r a c t i o n ~  P r o d u c t i o n}~~~~
{\sffamily\bfseries\Longstack{T r a n s p o r t a t i o n}}&
{\scshape\Longstack{O n - s i t e ~ E q u i p m e n t}}~~~~~~ 
{\bfseries\Longstack{T r a f f i c ~ D e l a y}} & 
{\setstackgap{L}{12pt}\large\Longstack{A l b e d o}}\\
\hline
x~~~~~x & x~~~~~~~~x&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's not really difficult to do it, but the result is simply unreadable, because we're not used to read vertically; signs or advertising using vertical text usually resort to all capitals.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\VT}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_vertical_text_seq { } { #1 }
  \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_vertical_text_seq { \\ }
  \end{tabular}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l cc cc cccc }
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Material} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Construction} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Use}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-9}
 Tool &
 \VT{Extraction/Production} &
 \VT{Transportation} &
 \VT{On-site~equipment} &
 \VT{Traffic~delay} &
 \VT{Albedo} &
 \VT{Carbonation} &
 \VT{Lighting} &
 \VT{PVI} \\
\midrule
\textit{PaLATE} & x & x & x \\
\textit{GreenDOT} & x & x & x \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Reducing the size or the leading wouldn't help either. Here's what I get with `\arraystretch` set to 0.8 and `\footnotesize` for the vertical text:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the result is indeed not readable. As an alternative, I have changed the content from the columns with that from the rows and now the table looks just fine.